# Hacer una comparación OR o AND por grupos en PHP sin repetir el criterio

Tags: php, revisión-de-código

Si en `PHP` necesito comparar varias variables, pero el criterio de comparación es invariable, una comparación `OR` la hago así:

```
if ($var1 == 5 || $var2 == 5 || $var3 == 5 || $var4 == 5 || $var5 == 5)
{
    echo "Alguien tiene 5";
}
```

Me pregunto si no habría una forma de resumir, de forma que compare al mismo tiempo si las todas variables son igual a 5.

Comment: Para la comparación `OR` se podría crear un arreglo que contenga todas las variables, y usar la función `in_list()` para comprobar si existe el valor en el mismo.

Comment: Por la via que lo hagas tienes que leer el valor de cada una de las variables. No creo que exista forma de hacerlo sin comparar las 5 variables. Si no tienes una cantidad fija de variables usa `in_array(5, $var_array)`. Pero el costo computacional es el mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar repetir el criterio con el `OR`, podrías usar la función [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php). La idea sería crear un array con todas las variables y usarlo para comprobar si ese valor existe con el `in_array`. Entonces el código que tienes:

```
if ($var1 == 5 || $var2 == 5 || $var3 == 5 || $var4 == 5 || $var5 == 5) {
    echo "Alguien tiene 5";
}
```

sería equivalente a hacer esto:

```
if (in_array(5, array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5))) {
    echo "Alguien tiene 5";
}
```

Si quieres añadir más variables, no haría falta que añadas `|| $nuevaVariable` al condicional, lo que harías es añadirla al `array` donde se va a buscar.

---

Para el `AND` podrías hacer algo parecido, pero en lugar de comparar si un valor está en un array, lo que harías sería crear un array que contenga las variables y el valor con las que quieres compararlas, entonces quitar los duplicados con [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) y comprobar cuántos elementos quedan en el array. Si sólo queda 1, entonces eso quiere decir que todos los elementos son iguales. Entonces un código com éste:

```
if ($var1 == 5 && $var2 == 5 && $var3 == 5 && $var4 == 5 && $var5 == 5) {
    echo "Todas las variables son 5";
}
```

Podría escribirse así:

```
if (count(array_unique(array(5, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5))) == 1) {
    echo "Todas las variables son 5";
}
```

Si quieres añadir más variables, no haría falta que añadas `&& $nuevaVariable` al condicional, lo que harías es añadirla al `array` donde se va a buscar y ya está.

---

Ojo: estos métodos no son más eficientes (se tienen que crear arrays, atravesarlos, comparar valores...), pero son más sencillos de escribir y no se repite  el criterio de condición.

Además, creo que quedan más vistosos y ordenados si no se reducen tanto y se crea primero el array y luego se opera sobre él. Por ejemplo:

```
$valores = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);

if (in_array(5, $valores)) {
    echo "Alguien tiene 5";
}
```

Comment: Gracias. ¿Y si tuviera que comparar que cualquiera de los valores es menor que cinco `< 5`, funcionaría poniendo algo así: `if (in_array(< 5, $valores)) {...` para el `OR` y `if (count(array_unique(array(< 5, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5))) == 1)`  para el  `AND`
?

Comment: No, eso no funcionaría tal cual. Lo que podrías hacer para el `OR` es encontrar el menor valor con `min` y comparar solo ese valor con < 5 (en el caso del `AND` sería el máximo valor con `max`)

Comment: Entonces es complicado...pues yo pensaba en algo que sirviera para cualquier tipo  de comparación: `=, >, <, <=, >= ...`